# Firebase notification: How to delete token from Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase messaging services for push notification in my iOS app. I am trying to delete the registered token from firebase using the following method.

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().deleteToken(withAuthorizedEntity: GCM_SENDER_ID, scope: kFIRInstanceIDScopeFirebaseMessaging, handler: { (result) in

   // What should be the expected result ???               

})
```

What should be the expected output from this function as I am not getting any acknowledgment that device is unregistered from FCM. I am passing `GCM_SENDER_ID` as AuthorizedEntity. Can anyone help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revokes access to a scope (action) for an entity previously
       authorized by `[FIRInstanceID tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:options:handler]`. This is an asynchronous call. So, call this on the main thread since InstanceID lib
is not thread safe. 
 Note, you can only have one `token` or `deleteToken` call for a given
 authorizedEntity and scope at a point of time.

Hope,it helps.

Comment: what to send in case of withAuthorizedEntity: ?

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Code**

```kotlin
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().deleteToken().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // do something
            } else {
                // do something
            }
        }
```